# Image is stretching in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6.1

[image]

I am working on `UIImageview` image. I downloaded the image above using `AsynchronousFreeLoader` and assigned it to imageview, but the image is stretching a lot.

I used the contentmode is `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`. I already tried to set it to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`, but it is also stretched.

Image size is 400 x 400 and send it to server.

Can anyone tell me how to show the image in imageview without stretching it?

Comment: Can u please add a screenshot so that I can help you to solve ur problem?

Comment: What's the size of the UIImageView?

Comment: @bneely UIImageView size is 300 x 250 and image size is 400 x 400

Comment: @iPhoneNerd plz find attachment of screen shot and plz suggest. thank u.